# Почему этот код работает? http, горутины

Tags: golang

```
var b int

func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", requset).Methods("get")
    router.HandleFunc("/change", change).Methods("get")
    http.Handle("/", router)

    // Start HTTP server
    fmt.Println("Server Start: ")
    http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:7777", nil)
}

func requset(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    count := 1000
    for index := 0; index < count; index++ {
        go http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:7777/change")
    }

}

func change(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    b = 10
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

функция change изменят переменнуюи `b`. Я думал, что должна быть ошибка, так как сотни горутин ёё пытаются изменить, или в пакете http предусмотрена какая-то блокировка? Как изменить код чтобы при изменении переменной `b` был одновременный доступ к памяти в которой хранится переменная `b`

Comment: Так тут и есть ошибка. Вы просто её не видите. Компилируйте с `-race` и смотрите на стектрейсы.

Comment: действительно, благодарю